# How do I POST string as a text file with libcurl?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I want to post data with libcurl to a discord webhook as a file, but since discord webhook have a limit (2000 characters), And my message are long, I want to post it as a text file.

I have this code working which post a string.

```
void sendWebhook(const char* content, const char* WEBHOOK) {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, WEBHOOK);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Which only works till it hits 2000 characters.

How would I POST a string as a text file to a webhook with libcurl?

I tried using this

```
void sendWebhookFile(string filePath, string webhook) {
    string s = "curl -F \"file1=\"" + filePath + "\"\" " + webhook;
    system(s.c_str());
}
```

but i want to directly send a string as a file, instead of a text file in a file path. Is that possible?

Comment: are you asking `how to create a file?`?

Comment: You may be looking for [`CURLOPT_MIMEPOST` option](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MIMEPOST.html); this is the direct equivalent of `-F` command line option. If you can make it work from the command line, it should be easy to translate into code.

Comment: I want to post a string AS a text file, but i dont want to create one. maybe a temporary one?

Comment: I can only find command from command line which take file path as input. i dont want that

Comment: discord's chat limit is 2000. https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

Comment: What does prevent you from following the example in the linked manual in the second comment?

Comment: Hint: `curl -XPOST https://example.com/ --lubcurl curl_post.c`